# Blender Image Orientation

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to composite a model into a photo in blender. The image is saved as a portrait but when opened in blender it appears landscape:

[image]

If I reverse the resolution values of the camera and rotate the background image it becomes distorted:

[image]

In the movie clip editor it is also landscape which makes it confusing to work with.

I want the the background image to fit inside the frame of the camera while also being in a portrait orientation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Some picture file can include information about the algining what can cause problem sometimes.Try to reexport the picture with Gimp or a photo editor.